How to get the target of a function call when its in the {{ }} notation vuejs
When using v-on, its possible to get the source of the event with the $event notation which then allows me to manipulate the html tag. For example:
<button @click="test($event.target)">Big red button, don't push it</button>
I want to be able to do the same thing in this scenario:
<p id="something">{{ function($event.target) }}</p>
So that in my function I can then go back and manipulate the p tag for example. Is that possible?
I've looked at the documentation and looked around on stackoverflow and I haven't found anything of the sort.

In the <button @click="test($event.target)">, the test represents the event handler which has access to current DOM element that fired this event, in the other case the function is not handler, it's function used to render something based on some arguments.
In order to get access to the element try to use template ref :
<script setup>
import { ref} from 'vue'

const something = ref(null)

function someFunction(){
   // now you've access to `something.value` and manipulate your element
}

</script>

<template>
  <p ref="something">{{ someFunction() }}</p>
</template>

